Altium don't recognize differential pair net naming
I am trying to make a differential pair in Altium Designer.
As I know from the documentation the net label should be <some_label>_P for one and <some_label>_N for another.
However not any <net_label> is OK for Altium. As you can see from the screenshot - the RS422RX diffferential pair still have a red wavy lavel near the pair sign and RS4 don't:

I have tried many different net label prefixes but still no clue why some work and another don't.
Are there any additional naming conveentions not mentioned in the documentation?

Are you using constraints manager for the project? Then you need to set the diff pairs up in constraints manager for them to transfer to the pcb

It also needs to be set up in project options, under options
